# How to match similar words?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, database

i have form like this =

```
Name 1
First Name  :  <input type='text' name='firstname'>
Middle Name :  <input type='text' name='middlename'>
Last Name   :  <input type='text' name='lastname'>


Name 2
First Name  :  <input type='text' name='firstname2'>
Middle Name :  <input type='text' name='middlename2'>
Last Name   :  <input type='text' name='lastname2'>
```

when input "Name 1" and "Name 2", i want the result like this :

```
`example : <br>
 Name 1 = michael smith <br>
 Name 2 = michael nick smith <br>
 Percentage similar of "Name 1" and "Name 2" is = 80% `
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use only this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php this is what you need.

```
$var_1 = 'PHP IS GREAT'; 
$var_2 = 'WITH MYSQL'; 

similar_text($var_1, $var_2, $percent); 

echo $percent; 
// 27.272727272727
```

live example of your code http://codepad.viper-7.com/nyHukz

```
$var_1 = 'michael smith'; 
$var_2 = 'michael nick smith'; 

similar_text($var_1, $var_2, $percent); 

echo $percent; 
//83.870967741935
```

Comment: You should post some caveats/warnings about this code. For example, `similar_text($var_1, $var_2, $percent) != similar_text($var_2, $var_1, $percent);`. Look in the comments: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Comment: @JSuar for that i have posted the link also.