# Mysql similar search with multiple keywords - sorting by most keywords in string

Tags: mysql, search, keyword

i know, there are many postings with "mysql" and "similar search" but i dont find the answer of my question. Maybe i am to blind :/

What i try do to
i have a (for example) three keywords -> dog cat house

and now i want to find all titles in my db with this keywords - but! i want to sort the result by most hits.

Results:
1) my dog and my cat is in the house (3)
2) i have a cat and a dog (2)
3) i have a cat in my house (2)
4) my house is big (1)
...

I tried the like funktion but it doesn work.
Is this possbile with mysql?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can also search for `FULLTEXT SEARCH`

Comment: so, it is not possible with the normal mysql commands?

Comment: You seem to have asked the same question in three different ways

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to match similar words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872553/how-to-match-similar-words)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a readable version of your needs, but this is **not intended for production** environment only for academic knowledge:

```
Select 
   if( INSTR(your_column, 'dog')>0 ,1,0) +
   if( INSTR(your_column, 'cat')>0 ,1,0) +
   if( INSTR(your_column, 'house')>0 ,1,0) as my_rate,
   *
from 
   ...
order by my_rate desc
;
```

**The right approach is the [fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)**

Comment: I use the query only for an admin-tool but i get an syntax error. Can you check it? Would be nice :)
http://pastebin.com/41TJpwHA

Comment: change `*` by `\`wp_posts\`.*`