# MySql Php Find Similar Values

Tags: php, mysql

I run a website where users have a username. They can change their usernames whenever they want. When them change their name, we check that that name isn't currently being used and then allow or not allow the change. On our site people often like to change their username to copy other peoples (make their name very similar to confuse other people of their identity). This isn't uncommon for the type of site we run.

Is way to easily check for usernames that are somewhat similar using a simple query?

Here are some examples of usernames that we would like to have a query match up.

```
testingman1 = testingman11
lionhead = Iionhead (one has an l and the other has a capital i)
sleepybears = sleeepybears
```

Any way to do a character by character count of the same letters in the same position and then determine based on the percentage if it is a copy of another user?

I know I'll most likely have to write a custom function, but just looking for some advice on how to make it as painless and not very system taxing process.

Comment: Try: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: Thanks a ton! I didn't know such a thing existed! I'll pry implement the php version of it (http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php). Not a big fan of creating functions in MySql.

Comment: just be careful. you may end up with false positives, e.g. two legitmately different names that do only differ by one character, like tommi and tammi.

Comment: Have a look at the soundex function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php. You would use $u = soundex( $username ); $u2 = soundex( $newName ); if( $u1 == $u2 ) { then pick another name }

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to match similar words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872553/how-to-match-similar-words)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

- `levenshtein(str1, str2)` that will return an integer witch is the distance between the two strings. 
  In PHP if one string is longer that 255 characters the function will return -1.
  More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php
- or if you want in percent you can use `similar_text ( string $first , string $second, [, float &$percent ] )`
  witch pass in the 3rd parameter the percent of similarity
  More info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Comment: Loading all the data into PHP to compare it? Not very efficient. There are several implementations of levenstein for MySQL, e.g. https://github.com/MartinZottmann/mysql-levenshtein I expect there are other functions for string comparison too.